# HTML5 Server Sent Events not working in TideSDK

Tags: tidesdk

I'm trying to use Server Sent Events in my desktop application using TideSDK 1.3.1-beta. The code functions flawlessly on localhost viewed through a webkit-based browser, but when running the program through TideSDK, nothing at all happens.

The Javascript I'm using is as such:

```
<script>
var source=new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
source.onmessage=function(event)
{
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";
 alert(event.data);
}
</script>
```

And the demo_sse.php page looks like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$time = date('r');
echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

I know it isn't just some silly mistake since, like I said, it works perfectly in the browser, but when running through TideSDK, nothing at all occurs. 
It is very important that I resolve this issue. If anybody can provide any insight, please let me know.

PS: Something weird I noticed: If I use "app" as the protocol in EventSource, such as `EventSource("app://demo_sse.php");` the program immediately crashes before the console can output the line about preprocessing the `demo_sse.php` file.

Comment: This might be an important bit of information. Strangely, I using a php file on a remote server such as `var source=new EventSource("http://somedomainame.com/demo_sse.php");` works perfectly fine in TideSDK. I suppose there's some issue with php on TideSDK's side of things. Maybe it doesn't like the content type header? How can I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');

header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$time = date('r');

echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";

flush();

?>
<script>

var source=new EventSource("demo_sse.php");

source.onmessage=function(event)

{

 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";


 alert(event.data);

}

</script>
```